# cp .iso /dev/sdd usb memory device full

Tags: cp, flash-memory

I was informed, from here, the best (easiest) way in linux to put a bootable iso file to a usb stick and have it be bootable to do an install is simply via `cp rhel-8.5-x86_64-dvd.iso /dev/sdd` where `sdd` is the block device my usb stick happens to show up as.  And this works.

But using my usb flash *disk* an Apricorn Fortress 256gb which I have used successfully many time...

- it was previously formatted as NTFS, and was full with like 2gb space left
- I then connected it to my rhel 7.9 pc and attempted a 10gb copy via `cp rhel-8.5-x86_64-dvd.iso /dev/sdd`
- `cp` responded with device full
- using `parted` and `mklabel gpt` did not resolve the problem.

what is happening?  should I be using `dd` instead of `cp` ?

Comment: What does `ls -l /dev/sdd` show?

Comment: Also check `head /sys/block/sdd/{dev,size}` - that way you know which size the kernel believes it to be, and whether the `/dev/sdd` device node points to the correct device. You can also use `blockdev --getsize64 /dev/sdd` to get the size in bytes.

Comment: Are you sure the stick hasn't been auto-mounted? I'm not sure how a `cp` to a block device file would deal with that case. I always use `dd`.

Comment: `ls -l /dev/sde` from RHEL 8.7 currently show `brw-rw----` 1 root disk 8, 64 <ar 7 07:36 /dev/sde

Comment: what I did last night though is connect it to win10 and disk management format as NTFS, then manually did disk tools optimize (trim?) and after that I was able to copy my rhel8.iso to it, which it currently has on it now